# Store a swift closure as a property on an objective-c class where the block is declared using a typedef

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8.1

OMG, for the life of me I can't get this to work.

- I've got a `typdef` in objective-c that looks like this:

```c
typedef void (^StringBlock)(NSString * string);
```

- I've got an objective-c class that has a property that allows you to store your own block of `StringBlock` type. That property is declared in objective-c like this:

```c
@property (nonatomic, copy) StringBlock onTextSubmitBlock;
```

- Assigning a block to it in objective-c looks like this:

```c
input.onTextSubmitBlock = ^(NSString * text) {

};
```

- I want to do the same thing from within a Swift class! The closest I've come to having something that works is this:

```c
input!.onTextSubmitBlock = {(StringBlock) in

}
```

That compiles, but I have no access to the argument I need (`(NSString * text)` in objective-c...)

I'm sure that once I get used to Swift this will be obvious, but what am I missing?

Comment: Did you try `input!.onTextSubmitBlock = { text in println(text) }`? It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close. You should be able to use it like this:

```
input!.onTextSubmitBlock = { text in
    println(text)
}
```

Swift will infer that `text` is an `NSString` from the declaration. Thera are a couple alternative ways you could declare this as well. Like this:

```
input!.onTextSubmitBlock = {
    println($0) // $0 is text
}
```

And this:

```
input!.onTextSubmitBlock = { (text: NSString) -> () in
    println(text)
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's so beautifully simple. But why would:

`input!.onTextSubmitBlock = { (text:NSString) in`

fail?

Comment: You can do it that way, but you'd have to include the return type as well, like this: `input!.onTextSubmitBlock = { (text: NSString) -> () in`

Comment: Nicely done. Thanks!

However, the compiler still complains about `input!.onTextSubmitBlock = { (text: NSString) -> () in`, saying `Cannot assign a value of type '(NSString) -> ()' to a value of type 'StringBlock!'`

Comment: Sorry for continued noobishness... Swift is weird.

I'm using this:

`input!.onTextSubmitBlock = { text in`

but if text is nil, program crashes with `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values`. It seems I can't deal with this using `let` or `!` or `?`, which are the only options I can think of...

Comment: Since you declared the block in Objective-C, it's being imported to swift as an implicitly unwrapped optional (Autocomplete would show it as `NSString!`). If you're running an Xcode 6.3 Beta you'll be able to add either __nullable or __nonnull to your Objective-C block (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) for an explanation. e.g. You could declare it as __nullable in Objective-C, and it'll become `NSString?` in Swift. __nonnull will become `NSString`. If you're not on the betas you will just have to wait for that feature.

Comment: Either way, if it can be null you'll need an `if let`.